# Get the last non-blank value in a row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to find the last value in row 20 of my Google Sheet [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VVJuARXKjTpx_ZxYjVINF2ryjYCOiX0kyGdGakeTC08/edit?usp=sharing). More data is added from time to time.

The formula I use for this is getting too long and I would need an easier way to get the same result without having to edit the formula each time a new column is inserted:

```
        =If(Q20 ="",
              If(P20 ="",
               If(O20 ="",
                If(N20 ="",
                 If(M20 ="",
                  If(L20 ="",
                   If(K20 ="",
                    If(J20 ="",
                     If(I20 ="",
                      If(H20 ="",
                       If(G20 ="",
                        If(F20 ="", "",
                           F20)
                        ,G20)
                       ,H20)
                      ,I20)
                     ,J20)
                    ,K20)
                   ,L20) 
                  ,M20)
                 ,N20) 
                ,O20)
               ,P20)
              ,Q20)
```

Comment: What does a google sheet have to do with java?

Comment: Yes, that function is beyond comprehension and I am sure there is a much better solution. Please explain what you are trying to achieve and share a view only version of the sheet as a picture is worth a 1,000 words. :-)

Comment: @f1sh Yes I guess I misread it and thought it said google sheets was Java, I edit the post to reflect that. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnA Sorry for late reply, I went ahead and added a example in post with a link. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to get the last non-blank value in a column. Try this:

`=+sort( transpose(F20:Q20), transpose( column(F20:Q20) * sign(len(F20:Q20)) ), false )`

Comment: Made a typo when Initially trying to set this but when trying to learn how to implement it put it in again and it worked perfectly. Thank you.